# Setter for a clr-property that is defined in an abstract base class with only a getter

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to declare a setter for a clr-property that is defined in an abstract base class with only a getter (and vice versa)?

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    public abstract string Test {
        get;
    }
}

class ConcreteClass : BaseClass{
    public override string Test {
        get { return string.Empty; }
        set { /* Some code*/} // This would be really pratically
    }
}
```

The same quesion may be asked for properties marked as virtual.

Comment: Your BaseClass is entirely abstract.  That should be an interface, problem solved.

Comment: In some cases, I don't like to make interfaces and would like more something like the above. But yes - an interface would solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is fortunately not possible. You cannot change an existing definition/contract.

There are ways around it, like the `new` keyword. Or using an interface.

Comment: new is not a way around it new is something different that looks like the same.
BaseClass foo = getFoo();
string myFoo = foo.Test;
and
ConcreteClass foo = (ConcreteClass)getFoo();
string myFoo = foo.Test; might yield different results for the _same_ object

Comment: Which definition/contract would be broken? It’s only an additional method in the derived class. But yes, it seems not possible. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sort of a workaround possible.

Declare a protected setter in the base class, then implement it in the concrete classes.

Like this:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract string Test { get; protected set; }

}

class Concrete : Base
{
    string s;
    public override string Test
    {
        get { return s; }
        protected set { s = value; }
    }
}
```

... but pretty, it ain't :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  this declaration is possible, however not what I'm looking for.