# Override base property with getter with setter and getter in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, abstract

I have a base object that implements a property with only a getter. In my subclass I'd like to implement both:

```
public ref class NTObject
{
  property ::System::String ^ Name {
    virtual ::System::String ^ get ();
  }
};

public ref class NTNamed
  : ROOTNET::NTObject,
    ROOTNET::Interface::NTNamed
{
  property ::System::String ^ Name {
    virtual ::System::String ^ get () override;
    virtual void set (::System::String ^ value);
  }
};
```

When I then write the following simple code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var n = new ROOTNET.NTNamed("hi", "there");
        Console.WriteLine(n.Name);
        n.Name = "hi there";
        Console.WriteLine(n.Name);
        var obj = n as ROOTNET.NTObject;
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
    }
```

I get a build error on the "n.Name = " line - "Property or indexer ROOTNET.NTObject.Name cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" - in short, it is missing the fact that I sub-classed with the NTNamed object. So, I replace the "override" keyword above with a "new" keyword. Now it will build, and the above code works correctly. However, I don't think the last two lines of the code snippit work - it will call NTObject's Name getter, not NTNamed's getter.

I have seen in stackoverflow other questions that talk about this problem in C#, but I figured since I had very fine grained control over how I could define the getter/setter I could get around these issues (see, for example, [C# Setter for an abstract getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075158/setter-for-a-clr-property-that-is-defined-in-an-abstract-base-class-with-only-a).

Is there a way that would behave as I've written the code above, with the override keyword, rather than the new keyword? Many thanks!